# Tomcat instruction: translation from .bat to .sh

Tags: tomcat, batch-file, sh, catalina

I'm trying to setup SSL communcation for an application that uses a tomcat server.
Unfortunately, the instructions are for the Windows version but the server I'm working on runs SUSE Linux.
Here's the [batch Script](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/bin/catalina.bat) and here the [shell script](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/bin/catalina.sh).

The instruction says to locate the line that contains ":execCmd". After that line, one has to insert

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=foo.jks" "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

I'm guessing the code to insert could be corrected by just leaving out the "set ".

As this appearst to overwrite the CATALINA_OPTS variable, my guess would be that putting this at the very first line might work.

However, before I mess up something or create an error that goes undetected later, I'd hope to get a second opinion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the usual way to give tomcat additional options is via a setenv.sh file in the $CATALINA_HOME/bin directory (that's the same where catalina.sh is located). If such a file exists, it is automatically read during tomcat startup. And if you want to prevent your setenv.sh from overwriting existing settings, the best way is:

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=foo.jks" 
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```